# Gradient in sections rather than linear

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make more obvious colors in a gradient. I want to be able to see the transitions between them. Like this example.

[image]

I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) example but I didn't manage to make it work as intended.

```css
#grad {
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #006723 0%, #00852D 25%, #009733 50%, #00A739 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

Comment: You need to stop those colors. For example `#006723` can be stopped at 25%.

Comment: and how do i stop them?

Comment: #006723 0%-25%, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the color stop values for the colors, otherwise it will extend till 100% and thus you get that faded effect.

For example: `#006723` now starts from `0` and extends till `25%` and the next color `#00852D` starts from that same stop point. You need not specify the start point for first and last point for the last color in this case though.

```css
#grad {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #006723 25%, #00852D 25%, #00852D 50%, #009733 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad"></div>
```

Comment: do you know if its possible to make the line between the transitions rounder like the image aswell?:)

Comment: You need to make use of radial-gradient in that case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient() and if you are stuck, I would suggest you to open a new question so that there is no mix up :)